# Perl REGEX on mac address

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the command "show mac-address-table dynamic" on a cisco switch via perl script. The output for the same as is follows:

```
Legend: * - primary entry
    age - seconds since last seen
    n/a - not available

vlan   mac address     type    learn     age              ports
------+----------------+--------+-----+----------+--------------------------
*   14  782b.cb87.b085   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi4/39
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes         15   Gi3/37
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi1/27
*  400  0017.c50f.704d   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi13/19
*  400  0006.8b05.a915   dynamic  Yes         10   Gi5/29
*  400  c0ea.e414.2f29   dynamic  Yes         10   Gi3/37
*  400  0017.c53e.166d   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi1/12
```

I am writing a script such that it takes out only the mac address having initial first 4 figures such as 0017.c5 or 0006b or c0ea.e4. Also, it should display the number of times they are repeated. I tried by writing the below code:

```
for my $line (@ver) {
    if (my ($mac_addr) = $line =~ /((?:[0-9a-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9a-f]{4})/) {
        $mac_addr = $1;
        if ($mac_addr =~ m/^(0017.c5)[0-9a-f]{2}.[0-9a-f]{4}/ or $mac_addr =~ m/^(c0ea.e5)[0-9a-f]{2}.[0-9a-f]{4}/ or $mac_addr =~ m/^(0006.b)[0-9a-f]{3}.[0-9a-f]{4}/){
            push (@sonic_macaddr, $mac_addr);
            for $it (@sonic_macaddr){
                $uniq{$it}++;
            }
        }
    }
}
print (Dumper(\%uniq));
```

I am not getting the required results. Please can somebody guide me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have problem with your regex. Just remove the `[.]` from the regex.

Secondly, you are pushing the result into the `@sonic_macaddr` array and then increasing the `$uniq` for every match. It is giving you wrong count. So remove that portion.

Here is how your if block looks like after the modification.

```
if ($mac_addr =~ m/^(0017.c5)/ or $mac_addr =~ m/^(c0ea.e5)/ or $mac_addr =~ m/^(0006.b)/){
    $uniq{$mac_addr}++;
}
```

Output for your sample Data:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '0017.c53e.166d' => 1,
      '0017.c59a.23aa' => 2,
      '0017.c50f.704d' => 1
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by giving you wrong count? What count does it give? Thanks.

Comment: You were doing `for $it (@sonic_macaddr){` every time for a match and it caused the wrong count. I may be wrong because you implemented the code.

Comment: Thanks. Should your if condition be kept in the for loop? or standalone as I am not getting the desired results. Thanks

Comment: @deep Just replace your if block `if ($mac_addr =~ m/^($mac_prefixes)/){...` with mine one. And see whether its the correct result or not.

Answer (score 3):

This match will always fail:

```
$mac_addr =~ m/^(0017.c5)[.]/
```

That looks for your desired prefix, followed by a period.  None of your mac address will have a period at the 8th character.

Perhaps the following reworking of your script will help you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ver = <DATA>;

my @mac_prefixes = qw(0017.c5 c0ea.e5 0006.b);
my $mac_prefixes = '(?:' . join('|', map quotemeta, @mac_prefixes) . ')';

my @sonic_macaddr;
my %uniq;

for my $line (@ver) {
    if (my ($mac_addr) = $line =~ /((?:[0-9a-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9a-f]{4})/) {
        $mac_addr = $1;
        if ($mac_addr =~ m/^($mac_prefixes)/){
            my $prefix = $1;
            push (@sonic_macaddr, $mac_addr);
            $uniq{$prefix}++;
        }
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%uniq;
dd \@sonic_macaddr;

__DATA__
Legend: * - primary entry
    age - seconds since last seen
    n/a - not available

vlan   mac address     type    learn     age              ports
------+----------------+--------+-----+----------+--------------------------
*   14  782b.cb87.b085   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi4/39
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes         15   Gi3/37
*  400  0017.c59a.23aa   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi1/27
*  400  0017.c50f.704d   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi13/19
*  400  0006.8b05.a915   dynamic  Yes         10   Gi5/29
*  400  c0ea.e414.2f29   dynamic  Yes         10   Gi3/37
*  400  0017.c53e.166d   dynamic  Yes          5   Gi1/12
```

Comment: How are you wanting to count them?  Are you wanting each prefix to be in a separate count?

Comment: What does map quotemeta means? Can you explain thanks.

Comment: Look up [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).  It's an important tool when inserting constants into a regular expression, as it will escape all the regex special characters.  In this case, all the .'s in your mac prefixes will be escaped so they will no longer match any character.  If you want to see it in action, just test it: `my @test = map quotemeta, @mac_prefixes; print "@test\n"`